# Iterating across Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem' link attributes is slow

Tags: c#, tfs, processing-efficiency

My purpose is to get WorkItems' link-relations of Parent and Child linktype.

It takes **90s** to process 165 `WorkItem`s,and Microsoft's Team Explorer uses **3s** only to show the same results.

```
foreach (WorkItem wi in wic)    //165 count,and takes 90s to process  
{  
    foreach(WorkItemLink wil in wi.WorkItemLinks) //I only need Parent and Child linktype
    {  
        string linktype = wil.LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString();  
        if (linktype == "Parent")  
        {  
            //some;  
        }  
        else if (linktype == "Child")  
        {  
            //some;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What types are `wic` and `wi.WorkitemLinks`? do they return array lists? If so you might see a performance improvement if you cast them in to some sort of collection e.g. IList<T> Iterating over arraylists is inherantly slow.

Comment: **wic** is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemCollection; **wi.WorkitemLinks** is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLinkCollection